# How can I get all records that matches a condition?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I get all records that matches a condition?  I have the following code it throws exception when  there are more than one result. How can I update my code to get all records.

```
protected override async Task<GetBillingByID_Action_Response> PerformActionAsync(GetBillingByID_Action_Request request)
{
    var Billing = await Context.Billings.Where(b => b.ProjectID == request.ID)
                                        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    var BillingDTO = Mapper.Map<BillingDTO>(Billing);

    return new GetBillingByID_Action_Response { Billing = BillingDTO };
}
```

I get this exception error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Enumerator failed to MoveNextAsync.

I also tried using `ToListAsync()`as:

```
var Billing = await Context.Billings.Where(b => b.ProjectID == request.ID).ToListAsync();
```

But I get this exception error

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration
>   or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: List`1 -> BillingDTO

Comment: if your `Billing` variable is list then your `BillingDTO` should also be list.

Comment: Hint: replace `var` with the explicit type and your issue might be more apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `SingleOrDefaultAsync` if you want to get all records, the `ToListAsync` is a correct choice based on what you need, however you need to map to a list of `BillingDTO` instead, since the `Biling` will be a list:

```
var BillingDTO = Mapper.Map<List<BillingDTO>>(Billing);
```

You need to change the following property as well:

```
return new GetBillingByID_Action_Response { Billing = BillingDTO };
```

The `BillingDTO` is a list now, so you need to change the `Billing` property in the `GetBillingByID_Action_Response` class to a list as well.